# Strange pattern matching behavior in Idris

Tags: pattern-matching, idris, totality

I stumbled upon what seems to be a strange behavior for Idris.

I'm using Emacs 25.3 on Ubuntu 17.04 and Idris 1.0.

Consider the following module:

```
module Strange

%default total

fun : Int -> Int -> Int
fun 0 0 = 0
fun 0 n = 10
fun n 0 = 20
```

When I load this (`C-c C-l`), I do not get a non-total function warning, and when I try it on the REPL I get this:

```
λΠ> fun 100 200
20 : Int
```

... as if Idris is not matching the literal `0` in the third clause. This behavior occurs also when loading the module in a normal shell (`idris Strange.idr`).

Shouldn't I get some kind of error about non-totality? Is this some bug in this version of Idris?

Comment: This is really strange indeed. When I load your file in Idris REPL I see compilation error about non-totality: `Strange.idr:6:1:Strange.fun is not total as there are missing cases`.

Comment: @Shersh Is your Idris version newer than 1.0? Like 1.1.1?

Comment: I don't think so. When I execute `idris --version` I see `1.0`.